# Troubles while migrate Eclipse Luna projects from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, 32bit-64bit

could you help me to fix a problem?

I worked on Eclipse Luna until recently and all my e4 projects worked well under Linux x86 (JDK7 and Eclipse were by 32 arch too).
Now I migrate to a newer computer with Linux 64 bit. I install both JDK7 either Eclipse Luna 64 bit. But I can't run my RCP application. Got many error like this:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-07-26 15:22:26.571
>   !MESSAGE Event Admin service is not available, unable to publish event
>   org.osgi.service.event.Event
>   [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/Context/context/SET].
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-07-26 15:22:26.590
>   !MESSAGE Event Admin service is not available, unable to publish event
>   org.osgi.service.event.Event
>   [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/renderer/SET].
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-07-26 15:22:26.591
>   !MESSAGE Event Admin service is not available, unable to publish event
>   org.osgi.service.event.Event
>   [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ApplicationElement/tags/ADD].
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-07-26 15:22:26.597
>   !MESSAGE Event Admin service is not available, unable to publish event
>   org.osgi.service.event.Event
>   [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/widget/SET].
>
> and so on...

What does it mean and how to fix it? I created my projects on 4.x Eclipse version.

What I tried:

- to put projects to a fresh workspace
- to clear and remake Eclipse product dependences

But I got the same errors

Comment: Are there any earlier messages in the .log file before these Event Admin mesages?

Comment: @greg-449 no, just runtime info:
`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
!SESSION 2015-07-26 16:27:53.892 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product runner.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it. Added org.eclipse.equinox.event bundle into Required Plug-ins section of my launcher. And also added it to Product dependences.
Everything worked out.